# Get List<DataRow> for BandedGridView (DevExpress)

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress 2009 controls in my WinForms C# project. I found one problem with BandedGridView (`_currentView`) on GridControl. DataSource for GridControl is typed List (`List<MismatchedInfo>()`). I wrote this code:

```
List<DataRow> apps = new List<DataRow>();
for (int i = 0; i < _currentView.DataRowCount; i++)
    apps.Add(_currentView.GetDataRow(i));
```

but in result list apps consists of 11 null datarows.
In debugger i see that:

```
_currentView.DataRowCount == 11
_currentView.GetDataRow(1) == null
_currentView.GetRow(1) != null (object MismatchedInfo from DataSource)
```

Could anyone tell me how to get List in this situation? What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I found answer in DevEx documentation :( "If the View's data source is a custom collection of objects, the GetDataRow method returns null" So, how can i create DataRows from my `List<MismatchedInfo>()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetDataRow is only used if your GridControl is bound to a DataTable. Instead, you should use the GetRow method and cast its object return value to an instance of your MismatchedInfo class.

```
for(int i = 0; i < _currentView.DataRowCount; i++)
{
    MistmatchedInfo info = (_currentView.GetRow(i) as MismatchedInfo);
    //do something
}
```